# How to switch to new window when using CodeceptJS

Tags: javascript, automated-tests, codeceptjs

I am trying to create a test with CodeceptJS (using WebdriverIO helper) in which I first log in on site A and then open a new separate window, where I have to check that everything is good, but I don't know how to "SwitchToWindow". There are some fucntions "SwitchTab", but on my site there are always new Window. Is that possible to change window, and works on it?

Comment: can you show „your site“ or explain in more detail what is exactly happening? I am unsure if I get your question right.

Comment: My site is actually on localhost, but it's looks like that: